Problems resetting rest post
I am trying to retarget an animation I have to a rig I have. My Rig is in a neutral standing pose (Not A or T) with it's arm bones just by the side.
My animation rig is in an A pose, so I want my rig to also be in an A pose
I put the rig in an A poste and Did the Pose > Apply > Applying the new pose as rest pose, but my model keeps breaking and I keep getting the message

"Actions on this armature will be destroyed by this new rest pose as
the transforms stored are relative to the old rest pose"

Can someone point me in the right direction?
If the file is needed, please let me know how, because I don't see a file upload button while posting this. Thanks

to share your file read the instructions: https://blend-exchange.com/

This is the procedure for applying a new rest pose: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224327/apply-pose-as-rest-pose-doesnt-work/224330#224330  Some Addons (like AutoRigPro) let you retarget animations even between different rest pose rigs.
